# In a Winforms RichTextBox control, how can I make the space BELOW a last-line link NOT clickable?

Tags: c#, winforms, hyperlink, richtextbox

In a Windows forms C# application, I have a number of RichTextBox controls that display a link as the last line of the text box, with no line break after.

The issue is that ALL of the white space that is physically below the link will be a clickable link.  I understand that empty white space below text generally serves as "part" of that line in windows--for example, put your cursor just below this post, and click and drag--you will select the last line.  But generally this does not include clickable links.  Try it with the title of this post--you can select the title, but your cursor is not the clickable "hand" until you are actually *directly* over the title.

I could get around this by changing my data to always include a trailing line break, or modify the point where I'm setting the text of the box to always add one.  But both of those seem messy.  Is there no way to make a RichTextBox's links act more like links in a web browser?

I can reproduce this behavior by creating a sample WinForms application, dropping in a RichTextBox, and using the designer to set the text to "http://www.google.com"  Anywhere BELOW the link will show the hand cursor.

I'm using Windows 7 / VS2010 / C# / .net Framework 4.0

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Adding a line break is messy?  Come on, it is richTEXTbox for crying out loud!  Use a WebBrowser if you want it to act like a browser.

Comment: I think using a line break is the best way, it's not very inconvenient. If there is another solution (which keeps using RichTextBox), it must be more complex than the one you pointed out.

Comment: @KingKing I think I figured out a way to do it with the RichTextBox; see answer below. But *definitely* more complex! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It would be good if the Cursor change event fired when hovering over a hyperlink but it doesn't :(

Jeremy's comment gave me an idea: surely the native RichTextBox control *does* receive some type of notification when the user hovers over a hyperlink, it apparently just is not exposed by the WinForms wrapper class.

A bit of research confirms my supposition. A RichTextBox control that is set to detect hyperlinks sends a [`EN_LINK` notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787970.aspx) to its parent through the [`WM_NOTIFY` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775583.aspx). By processing these `EN_LINK` notifications, then, you can override its behavior when a hyperlink is hovered.

The WinForms wrapper handles all of this in private code and does not allow the client to have any direct control over this behavior. But by overriding the parent window's (i.e., your form) window procedure ([`WndProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx)), you can intercept `WM_NOTIFY` messages manually and watch for `EN_LINK` notifications.

It takes a bit of code, but it works. For example, if you suppress the `WM_SETCURSOR` message for all `EN_LINK` notifications, you won't see the hand cursor at all.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct CHARRANGE
{
   public int cpMin;
   public int cpMax;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct NMHDR
{
   public IntPtr hwndFrom;
   public IntPtr idFrom;
   public int code;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct ENLINK
{
   public NMHDR nmhdr;
   public int msg;
   public IntPtr wParam;
   public IntPtr lParam;
   public CHARRANGE chrg;
};

public class MyForm : Form
{
   // ... other code ...

   protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
   {
      const int WM_NOTIFY    = 0x004E;
      const int EN_LINK      = 0x070B;
      const int WM_SETCURSOR = 0x0020;

      if (m.Msg == WM_NOTIFY)
      {
         NMHDR nmhdr = (NMHDR)m.GetLParam(typeof(NMHDR));
         if (nmhdr.code == EN_LINK)
         {
            ENLINK enlink = (ENLINK)m.GetLParam(typeof(ENLINK));
            if (enlink.msg == WM_SETCURSOR)
            {
                // Set the result to indicate this message has been handled,
                // and return without calling the default window procedure.
                m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
                return;
            }
         }
      }
      base.WndProc(ref m);
   }
}
```

Unfortunately, that's the easy part. Now comes the ***ugly hack*** where we work around the default behavior of the control that you describe, where it treats the remainder of the control's height as part of the last line if the last line is a hyperlink.

To do this, we need to get the current position of the mouse pointer and compare it against the position of the hyperlink text that the control has detected. If the mouse pointer is within the hyperlinked line, we allow the default behavior and show the hand cursor. Otherwise, we suppress the hand cursor. See the commented code below for a potentially better explanation of the process (obviously, `rtb` is your RichTextBox control):

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
   const int WM_NOTIFY    = 0x004E;
   const int EN_LINK      = 0x070B;
   const int WM_SETCURSOR = 0x0020;

   if (m.Msg == WM_NOTIFY)
   {
      NMHDR nmhdr = (NMHDR)m.GetLParam(typeof(NMHDR));
      if (nmhdr.code == EN_LINK)
      {
         ENLINK enlink = (ENLINK)m.GetLParam(typeof(ENLINK));
         if (enlink.msg == WM_SETCURSOR)
         {
            // Get the position of the last line of text in the RichTextBox.
            Point ptLastLine = rtb.GetPositionFromCharIndex(rtb.TextLength);

            // That point was in client coordinates, so convert it to
            // screen coordinates so that we can match it against the
            // position of the mouse pointer.
            ptLastLine = rtb.PointToScreen(ptLastLine);

            // Determine the height of a line of text in the RichTextBox.
            // 
            // For this simple demo, it doesn't matter which line we use for
            // this since they all use the same size and style. However, you
            // cannot generally rely on this being the case.
            Size szTextLine = TextRenderer.MeasureText(rtb.Lines[0], rtb.Font);

            // Then add that text height to the vertical position of the
            // last line of text in the RichTextBox.
            ptLastLine.Y += szTextLine.Height;

            // Now that we know the maximum height of all lines of text in the
            // RichTextBox, we can compare that to the pointer position.
            if (Cursor.Position.Y > ptLastLine.Y)
            {
               // If the mouse pointer is beyond the last line of text,
               // do not treat it as a hyperlink.
               m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
               return;
            }
         }
      }
   }
   base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Tested and working… But did I mention that this is an ugly hack? Treat it more like a proof of concept. I certainly don't recommend using it in production code. I'm in fairly strong agreement with Hans and Jeremy that you should either take the simpler approach of adding a line break, or use a more appropriate control designed to display hyperlinks.

Comment: Thanks--this is cool.  I agree, it's a pretty ugly hack.  I'll try to find a 3rd party control that meets my needs.

Answer (score 3):

> Anywhere BELOW the link will show the hand cursor.

You need to put a line break to see the text cursor below the link not the hand cursor. Its by design.

> I could get around this by changing my data to always include a
>   trailing line break, or modify the point where I'm setting the text of
>   the box to always add one. But both of those seem messy. Is there no
>   way to make a RichTextBox's links act more like links in a web
>   browser?

No. Put a line break after. Or set the RichTexbox DetectUrls property to false. Or as Hans mentioned use a Web Browser. Or use a 3rd party or open source RichTextBox control.

It would be good if the Cursor change event fired when hovering over a hyperlink but it doesn't :(